# beliefs in a partially randomised perfect bayesian equilibrium

Tags: game-theory

Suppose I have a game in extensive form as follows. Player 1 moves first and chooses R, M or L. If he chooses R, the game ends. Otherwise, the game reaches a non-trivial information set of player 2. At this information set, player 2 chooses either action l or r and the game ends.

The payoffs (in normal form) are as follows:

[Ll Lr
Ml Mr
Rl Rr] =

=[4,1 0,0
3,0 0,1
2,2 2,2]

The NE/SPNE are: (L,l), and (R,(q,1-q)) with q\in[0;1/2], the latter of which includes the pure strategy NE (R,r).

Clearly l is sequentially rational as long as the belief that player to plays L is larger than 0.5. Also, such beliefs are consistent because if l is played, L is best response which implies belief equals 1 by consistency. Hence, (L,l) with belief equal to 1 is PBE.

For (R,r), the belief must be weakly smaller than 0.5 by seq rationality (and consistency of beliefs has no bite as action r is not played in equilibrium), and thus for it to be PBE.

Now, for the remainder partially randomised equilibria, I am not sure. I am reasoning that in order for player 2 to find it sequentially rational to mix between l and r, it must be that both l and r are sequentially rational (so that player 2 is indifferent), which implies that the belief is 1/2. Furthermore, the beliefs are consistent since in the partially randomised equilibria player 1 plays R and the information set of player 2 is off the equilibrium path (so any beliefs are consistent). Is this correct?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

There are slightly different definitions of consistency for beliefs. Your notion of PBE assumes (what some people call) *weak consistency*: off the equilibrium path, any belief is weakly consistent. Under weak consistency, your argument is correct.